# org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error preparing statement. Cause: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

This problem occurs with a small probability. My business scenario is like this: start a timer and execute a select statement every 30 seconds to get data from the MySQL database. However, the following problems sometimes occur:

[image: 1]

Comment: Could you also post some code?

Comment: Does this answer your question [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: I found a solution to the problem. This problem is caused by my SqlSession being shared by multiple threads. If you encounter similar problems, you can check whether your SqlSession is used by multiple threads.

Comment: My SqlSession is being shared by multiple threads, and each thread executes different select statements. Could this be a problem caused by Mybatis' cache? I can't be sure of this